# What is the ledger in EOS?

Tags: smart-contract, transactions

When I create a smart contract, e.g: game. what does the ledger store? (EOS tokens, or heathy points, level of user). 
If the ledger stores heathy points, level, so how I can push it into block (Please kindly give me some code reference).

Answer (score 0):

The data is stored in tables which resides in ram so it can be there in ram only.Due to the architecture of eosio you can not push the state data to block. It only stored in ram.To create a table and store data into that table refer this https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/using-multi-index-tables

Comment: Thank you, but I means the transaction, which can store in block, right?

Comment: All Transactions are stored in blocks.So, you want code to do transaction ?

Comment: No, I want to know the flow of code. I want to select feature on contract to store in block.

Comment: Contract cannot store block.Because it's stored only in chain.

Comment: Yep, I know. I means in a contract, I have a struct of data. So I want to chose some field in this and push to block.

Comment: okay understood! if you have any idea about eosio.token contract in which we take a field in transfer action called "memo"...simillarly you can do it in your contract to add data to your transaction..but recomended way is to store data in tables only!

Comment: Anytime brother :-)

Comment: I have a doubt if ledger store value that it means it store it in the block .?

Comment: No data resides in block data storage can be done in ram only by multi-indexed tables. Please correct me if i am wrong!